# How to fetch data using every .json in a folder?

Tags: angularjs, json

I need to split my .json file into small pieces and place them in a folder, and then use angular.extend to have a catch'em all array, how do I do it?

```
(function() {
  (function() {
    var AggregateController;
    AggregateController = function($http) {
      var vm;
      vm = this;
      vm.inserzioni = [];
      $http.get("inserzioni.json").success(function(data) {
        vm.inserzioni = data;
      });
    };
    AggregateController.$inject = ['$http'];
    angular.module('realEstate').controller('AggregateController', AggregateController);
  })();

}).call(this);
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what your specific problem is. It's not clear where you are stuck. Also what server side language are you using?

Comment: Right now I have big .json file, I fetch data from it and place its data inside `vm.inserzioni = []`, but what I want is to modify my controller to let that `vm.inserzioni` would be populated using every little .json file inside a specific folder, and don't bother about server side, doing everything in the front end for this project is enough

Comment: then you would need to manually create array of all the url's or just file names and a variable that concatenates to the url

Comment: there's nothing capable of fetch every .json inside a folder and put their data into an array, without hardcoding every file?

Comment: only using server code to read the directory

Comment: damn thank you dude

Comment: Think about it...how secure would anything be if you could simply scan any directory on any site from your browser

Comment: yes yes I know, but public folders exist, don't they? It's just that I need to access harmless files and display them into some pages

Comment: public only means that that level can be accessed from web...anything out of it is not web accessible at all. Does not mean that a browser can read it. You need server code to do that ...period